# Spreading a single columns data over a 2D Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to make a grid which has 8 x 4 boxes and is populated with names from one column of data. Instead the following lists them. How would I achieve this? I am using VB.Net for the code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSEntrants" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT tblItems.fileID, tblEntrants.AccountID, tblAccounts.contactname

FROM tblItems
INNER JOIN tblEntrants
ON tblItems.fileID = tblEntrants.fileID
INNER JOIN tblAccounts
ON tblEntrants.accountID = tblAccounts.AccountID

WHERE tblEntrants.fileID=tblItems.fileID

ORDER BY tblEntrants.dateAdded ASC">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="gdvEntrants" width="100%" runat="server" style="font-size:1.8em" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="fileID" DataSourceID="DSEntrants" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="contactname"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You can use `datalist` or `listview`. There are several examples and tutorials to make table layout for these controls.